# I need the scheme of iRobot Create 2

Tags: irobot-create, mechanism, electronics, electric

I've tried to drill a number of holes in my iRobot.

I've missed one of them and I need the electronic scheme of iRobot Create 2 for trying to restore this input of the data cable.

Can you help me with that, please?

[image: Photo of PCB]

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Raz. Have you tried contacting the manufacturer? I would doubt the schematics are freely available. I couldn't see where you drilled holes in the pictures. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I've tried to drill holes in the wrong place. I've drilled it exactly in the connector ( where I need to connect the data cable). Do you have the Email of the manufacture?   Thanks

Comment: I bet if you read this page carefully, you'll find a way to contact the manufacturer: http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2/Projects.aspx

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Raz, but I'm afraid that questions which can only be answered by the technical support team for a specific manufacturer or supplier aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. *[Practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* are always welcome here though, so if you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a technical support query.

Answer (score 2):

The schematic for the main board on the iRobot Create 2 is currently not available. It is advised to remove the plastic top cover before drilling into the electronics below. (This is good practice for all electronics!) As suggested by another user, perhaps the manufacturer will be able to help you directly.

<sup>Please note that while I'm an iRobot employee, the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.</sup>